# Multiuser chatting program using RMI

Tags: java, rmi, distributed-computing

I'm working on an RMI chatting application, and one of its features is to allow the user to chat with more than one friend at the same time.

My approach to design these scenario is as follows: there will be an object bind to the registry, any user(client) wants to log in to the application will call a log in method on that object which returns a session object, so every user log in to the application will gain a session object if successfully logged in.

These session objects contain a list of Chat Room objects, which will be used to open a conversation pipe between 2 or more users.  The chat room object would contains a method that allows the user to add any number of members to a chat room.

This is my approach.  If anyone sees something not suitable, or has another approach which is better, please let me know.

Comment: I would consider a traditional sockets architecture that commmunicates via your own protocol rather than RMI for a chat application.

Comment: @us2012 Why?  This seems to be like an over complication (not that RMI it self is simple, but it covers all the network transportation) - We did something similar.  I made one of my juniors do this using sockets and then do it using RMI, lets just say they preferred the RMI solution -IMHO